# Challenging $O(2^{n/2})$ for hash collisions using quantum computers

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-256, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis

In "[Finding Hash Collisions with Quantum Computers by Using Differential Trails with Smaller Probability than Birthday Bound](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/213)" the authors Akinori Hosoyamada and Yu Sasaki state that it may be possible to perform collision attacks with of a lower order than $O(2^{n/3})$ using BHT [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002). Bernstein remarked for BHT that it would have the same space-time complexity or worse than classical attacks [[2]](http://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf).

However, the attack seems specific to increasing the number of rounds that can be attacked, without a direct result on the full hash algorithm (in this case AES and Whirlpool).

Does this result have any direct or indirect impact on SHA-256? In other words could these findings have a significant impact on the space-time complexity of finding collisions for SHA-256?

If so, can a space-time complexity be given? Or are the results too experimental for that to be calculated?

---

1. Brassard, G., Høyer, P., Tapp, A.: [Quantum cryptanalysis of hash and claw-free functions.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002) In: LATIN 1998. LNCS, vol. 1380, pp. 163{169. Springer (1998)
2. Bernstein, D.J.: [Cost analysis of hash collisions: Will quantum computers make SHARCS obsolete?](http://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf) In: SHARCS (2009)